# How to have unicode plain text in request?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-requests

I have a string with the character ý. I have it in python as \u00fd and it even prints to the console correctly. However when i pass this string to requests.get it is changed to %C3%BD. How can I make the request pass the ý character without changing it?

Comment: Is this actually causing as problem?  Encoding unicode characters for transport over the internet is not unusual, and is not usually problematic unless the receiving end is unable to decode.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it.

Requests are URL in a special form. URL have a predefined format. In such format, all characters but ascii alphanumeric, and `.`, `-`, `_`, `~` must be encoded with the percent encoding.

Not doing that will make web much less interoperable: *ý* is \u00fd just for you (OK, now UTF-8 is standard for web, but few years ago it was not so, and we still have a lot of old web tools).

So your *ý* should always coded with percent encoding, and `requests` module just apply standard web rules. If you want to be non interoperable, you should write the url by yourself. Requests is done to simplify all details of web (HTTP protocols).